# Relative Positioning vs. Absolute

Tags: css, css-position

The website is www.cleantelligent.com/tour/

This image, as a background, has tooltips and links on it.

The issue is that, if you re-size the window, the image and title (the main div, I think) moves left and right. This means that the "Take the Tour" sub-head isn't always aligned perfectly underneath the "Tour" Title in the black bar above. They should be lined up down the left so that the image is centered underneath the header content.

Is it my positioning that's causing this? If so, how can I fix it? I've tried positioning it absolutely, but that collapses the page and the footer pops up to the middle.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float: none !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
width: 960px !important;
```

Add that to your styling for #primary in your css. You have some unnecessary styling being applied.

Comment: This worked! What unnecessary styling is being applied? I'm trying to streamline the site, so that would be good info to have...
Thanks!

Comment: The div with id=#primary had float right being applied to it which was causing the margin to be off so it would not stay centered. Also the width was not set. You probably have some styling that was being applied elsewhere in your stylesheet.